# Check if array value changed or not into foreach loop php?

Tags: php, arrays

We have a array like this:

```
Array(
[0]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h1' [count]=>23)
[1]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h1' [count]=>25)
[2]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h1' [count]=>40)
[3]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h1' [count]=>50)
[4]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h1' [count]=>23)
[5]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h2' [count]=>44)
[6]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h2' [count]=>52)
[7]=>Array([HospitalName]=>'h2' [count]=>49)

)
```

I want to calculate h1 and h2  sum of count values.

```
sum of => h1[count]=>161
sum of => h2[count]=>145
```

How can I do with PHP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In your specific case, what did you try so far? Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another container which will hold the sum of those values from that array:

```
$sum = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    // simple initialization
    if(!isset($sum[$values['HospitalName']])) {
        $sum[$values['HospitalName']] = 0;
    }
    $sum[$values['HospitalName']] += $values['count'];
}
```

Basically, you just use the `HospitalName` as your key, then every time the corresponding key matches in the loop, it will just sum it to its designated hospital name.

[Here's what `$sum` would look like](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vCwxlp)

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` loop for that:

```
 $sums = [];

 foreach ($myArray as $values) {
    if (isset($sums[$values['HospitalName']])) {
        $sums[$values['HospitalName']] += $values['count'];
    } else {
        $sums[$values['HospitalName']] = $values['count'];
    }
 }
```